# ValueError: year is out of range pyplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import os
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import  pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt

pp = PdfPages('multipage.pdf')

pth = "D:/Technical_Data/"
for fle in os.listdir(pth):
    df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(pth, fle),usecols=(0, 4))
    if not df.empty:
       df=df.astype(float)
       days = df['indx']
       value = df['Close']
       plt.plot_date(x=days, y=value,fmt="r-")
       plt.title(fle)
       plt.ylabel("Price")
       plt.grid(True)
       pp.savefig()
pp.close()
```

I am iterating through files in directory, and saving all graphs to pdf file. The date is in the following format `20150101`.

But it throws the error:

> ValueError: year is out of range

Sample data

```
indx    open    High    Low Close   Volume
20140103    31.9823 32.1511 31.8382 32.1213 2034100
20140103    5.28    5.29    5.26    5.27    10387300
20140103    33.9    34.03   33.77   34  930800
20140103    10.62   10.63   10.51   10.6    2004500
20140103    3.42    3.49    3.42    3.49    3837600
20140103    1.69    1.71    1.685   1.705   6870300
20140103    42.5    43.61   42.3    43.47   255500
```

Comment: It's hard to debug code without example input. Please print the value of `days` variable and post it, I suspect that the problem is there.

Comment: @TonyBabarino added in question

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the format of days list. You have to convert those values to DateTime type or float representing days since 0001-01-01 UTC.

From matplotlib.pyplot [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html):

> plot_date(x, y, fmt='bo', tz=None, xdate=True, ydate=False, **kwargs)
>
> x and/or y can be a sequence of dates represented as float days since 0001-01-01 UTC.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert df['indx'] to pandas DatetimeIndex

```
# df=df.astype(float) # do not covert yymmdd to float
days = pd.to_datetime(df['indx'].astype(str), format='%Y%m%d')
plt.plot_date(x=days, y=value, fmt="r-")
```